# Mysql-proxy randomly overloads the system until I kill it

Tags: windows, mysql

I'm using mysql-proxy 0.8.3 on a Windows 7 system.

Sometimes, I get the following debug message in the log :

> (debug) .\chassis-event-thread.c:254: recv() from event-notify-fd
>   failed: Unknown error

and mysql-proxy process starts to use 25% of the CPU (on a quad-core) until I kill it. It continues to handle queries properly while it overloads the system.

The same queries/scripts doesn't always trigger the problem. I have very no idea of how to fix it.

Comment: MySQL Proxy is still considered an Alpha release. Report it as bug http://bugs.mysql.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with mysql proxy and windows but I did some investigation. I found mysql-proxy source and your error is logged from here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql-proxy-developers/mysql-proxy/0.8/view/head:/src/chassis-event-thread.c#L252 (I guess 2 line difference is from source code formatting). It looks like recv from line 238 returns E_NET_WOULDBLOCK value. On line 57 there is definition (you said you are on windows)

```
#define E_NET_WOULDBLOCK WSAEWOULDBLOCK
```

So real error is WSAEWOULDBLOCK. Searching for it I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14549541

> WSAEWOULDBLOCK is not really an error but simply tells you that your
>   send buffers are full. This can happen if you saturate the network or
>   if the other side simply doesn't acknowledge the received data.

I guess it is an error in mysql proxy. It is probably falling to infinite loop trying to recv from socket which is busy/empty/dead (and that's why 100% cpu usage). Maybe you could try with version from master (I don't know if there is a windows build)?